# Getting the output of an xslt transformed file in XML format

Tags: xml, browser, stylesheet

I have transformed one XML file to an another XML file (in desired structure) using XSLT. However i am unable to view the transformed file in XML format. It shows me plain text values.

This is my original XML  file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl.xsl"?>
<NewDataSet>
<Table>
 <IMPORT_ID>2</IMPORT_ID>
 <SEQ_NO>1</SEQ_NO>
 <LEVEL_TAG>RANDOMISATIONDATA</LEVEL_TAG>
 <INSERTED>2004-01-21T12:42:53+05:30</INSERTED>
 <INSERTED_BY>kfsv433</INSERTED_BY>
</Table>
   </NewDataSet>
```

And i coverted it to my desired output using the following XSLT :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
  <xsl:apply-templates /> 
 </xsl:template> 
 <xsl:template match="IMPORT_ID"> 
 <IMPORT_ID SEQ_NO="{SEQ_NO/text()}"/> 
 </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the output as

```
1RANDOMISATIONDATA2004-01-21T12:42:53+05:30kfsv433
```

I can see that what ever XSLT i have implemented is showing the correct result but i need to get this in XML format.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Could you maybe format you answer better (using the "code" formatting correctly) so we could see what the output looks like? Also, could you supply a snippet of the XSLT perhaps?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution and explanation. :)

Comment: You said you aren't able to view the result as XML, but you didn't say how you tried. Did you use a browser? A text editor? If "It" shows you plain text values, what exactly is "it"?

Comment: I am editing it in a notepad. saving it and viewing it in browser. IE 7

Comment: When browsers open an XML document, they apply their own stylesheet for rendering in pretty format. If the document has an `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction (and the browser honors it) then it will apply this stylesheet (XSLT _or CSS_) before rendering. **Any element from an XML vocabulary unknown by the browser and without style information will be rendered as unstyled inline block.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you want this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="IMPORT_ID">
        <IMPORT_ID SEQ_NO="{following-sibling::SEQ_NO[1]/text()}"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Table>
        <IMPORT_ID>2</IMPORT_ID>
        <SEQ_NO>1</SEQ_NO>
        <LEVEL_TAG>RANDOMISATIONDATA</LEVEL_TAG>
        <INSERTED>2004-01-21T12:42:53+05:30</INSERTED>
        <INSERTED_BY>kfsv433</INSERTED_BY>
    </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<IMPORT_ID SEQ_NO="1"/>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **All text nodes are matched by a template with empty body**, which overrides the default XSLT processing, so the text nodes are now not copied to the output.
2. **`SEQ_NO` is *not* a child of `IMPORT_ID` -- it is a sibling**.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very informative! But when i execute the XML , it does'nt show any result. I have a doubt if the XML is correct . I am including it here. Can you please check it ? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl.xsl"?>

<NewDataSet> 
  <Table>
    <IMPORT_ID>2</IMPORT_ID>
    <SEQ_NO>1</SEQ_NO>
    <LEVEL_TAG>RANDOMISATIONDATA</LEVEL_TAG>
    <INSERTED>2004-01-21T12:42:53+05:30</INSERTED>
    <INSERTED_BY>kfsv433</INSERTED_BY>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>

Comment: @hima: Yes, I alwas run my answers before publishing them. This transformation produces the same, correct result when run with all the 7 XSLT 1.0 processors that I have. Seems you are using XSLT in the browser and that XSLT processor may be buggy, or you may be trying to apply a second transformation on the result of a first transformation, which AFAIR IE doesn't support.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a browser. use a real xslt processor such as http://saxon.sourceforge.net.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the default output, which means that your IMPORT_ID template is not executing.

Try the following templates instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Table"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Table"> 
    <IMPORT_ID SEQ_NO="{SEQ_NO}/{IMPORT_ID}"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But when u say response , do you mean in my original xml file ?

Comment: I still dont get any output , the page remains blank :(